# didReceiveMemoryWarning in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, didreceivememorywarning

I am starting a new project (without ARC) targeting iOS 6. From [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html):

> Use this method to deallocate all noncritical objects associated with
>   your view controller. On iOS 6, you can also use this method to
>   release references to view objects.

My question is after we deallocate "noncritical objects" within `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, when can we reinstate the "noncritical objects" again ?

I am asking this because since `viewDidUnload` will never be called in iOS6, I reckon that `viewDidLoad` will not be called the second time before program termination. Am I right on this?

Comment: "I reckon that viewDidLoad will not be called the second time before program termination ... (Am I right on this ?)" Yes.

Comment: Why would anyone not use ARC???? Just askin'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and kind assistance.  Have started my first project before ARC was out and have got used to the RC scheme.  Have heard that ARC should not have any performance penalty and can save considerable work.  But I am quite comfortable with the non-ARC scheme and don't feel there is that much overhead in keeping an eye on r values.

Comment: Have actually planned to get myself familiar with ARC and give it a try.  Really like to hear the opinion of those who are familiar with both ARC and non-ARC.  Another factor is I have a feeling that for importing 3rd party code set such as ZXing (QR Code scanner), using the non-ARC scheme could be more straight forward.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My opinion? ***ARC!!!*** It's just a simple compiler flag for the non-ARC files.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  On second thought, I wish to say that I do feel that ARC is a very good concept since it saves coding work and does not affect performance (It definitely should reduce the chance of coding error also).  Being accustomed to something is not an excuse not to try something new and better ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use lazy loading for your non-critical data. Clear up this data in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Then the data will be lazy loaded again the next time you try to access it.

Comment: And here is some actual code illustrating what @rmaddy said: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#SECvcmem

Comment: Thank you all for your detailed answer and helpful comments.